# how to convert bit datatype to varchar in sql

Tags: c#, mysql

How to convert BIT datatype to Varchar in sql ?

I tried CAST

> `CAST(IsDeleted as Varchar(512))`

But it didn't work....

Note: **IsDeleted** is a BIT datatype and I need to convert it into Varchar or Int

Comment: Why is this tagged for both MySQL and SQL Server?  Which database are you really using?

Comment: Did you get an error message? _didn't work_ isn't very helpful

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a bit to a Varchar? What Varchar do you expect for a zero bit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming this is MySQL, you can't cast to `VARCHAR`. The allowable types are shown [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast); they're listed after the `CONVERT` function explanation.

You can cast to `CHAR(1)` though. For example:

```
CAST(b'11' AS CHAR(1))
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN IsDeleted = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS IsDel
FROM
    Table
```

Answer (score 5):

is the attribute **`nullable`**?

Try

```
CONVERT(varchar, ISNULL(isDeleted,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CAST(IsDeleted AS INT) AS IsDeleted
```

This should work I just tried it in SSMS and it works like a charm

Comment: Thanks, the following variation worked for me:  CAST(IsDeleted AS VARCHAR) AS IsDeleted